# Blazor / MudBlazor Validation Inside Table

Tags: blazor, fluentvalidation, mudblazor

I have a Blazor App using MudBlazor components.  Im am trying to validate entry into a TextField contained in a table Td.

I embed the form inside the Td and it works, but it validates every row.  I then try using the SelectedItemChanged event to capture the object for that row and put the Td inside an if statement that checks the context against the SelectedItem.  The logic works but when clicking into a new cell the last cell un-renders, all values are still there in the background.

Anyone got validation working inside a MudBlazor Table know what's going on here?

```
@if (context.VariableName == currentVariableSelected.VariableName)
{
    <MudTd>
        <MudForm Model="@context" @ref="@localVariableForm" Validation="@(localVariableValidator.ValidateValue)" ValidationDelay="500">
            <MudTextField @bind-value="@context.VariableName" For="@(() => context.VariableName)"
                          Immediate="true" DisableUnderLine="true" Class="mt-n3" T="string"
                          TextChanged="@((string name) => OnLocalVariableNameChanged(name, context))">
            </MudTextField>
        </MudForm>
    </MudTd>
}
else
{
    <MudTd>
        <MudTextField @bind-value="@context.VariableName" For="@(() => context.VariableName)"
                      DisableUnderLine="true" Class="mt-n3" T="string">
        </MudTextField>
    </MudTd>
}
```

Same thing occurs if you move the Td to the outside of the if.

Comment: Can you create an example that reproduces your problem? https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet

Comment: This was a dumb mistake, using @bind-value on a text field doesnt work, works fine on text, datalabels etc. Just have to up the logic to get the validation working